# How many digits are in N factorial

Tags: c++, c

I have the following problem, as says in the title: For each value of N, print out how many digits are in N!. For example, if n=32000, I should get 130271.
I have thought about a recursive solution. It works for smaller numbers, but for the above example it prints 31997. I am convinced that my thinking is wrong, but I can't really find a rule for bigger numbers. Somewhere, n! begins to skip steps, I think. I mean, it does not increases with a digit, but with two or three.
I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//For each value of N, print out how many digits are in N!.

int how_many(int n){
    if( n <= 3)
        return 1;
    if( n == 4)
        return 2;
    if( n == 5 || n == 6)
        return 3;
    if( n >= 7)
        return 1 + how_many(n-1);

    }


int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("The number n is : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int counter = 0;

    counter = how_many(n);

    printf("n! has %d digits", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing is really `log10(N!)`.  Once you realize that, you can use Stirling's Approximation or one of the other techniques explored here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138194/approximating-log-of-factorial

Comment: Or you could just use `lgamma` from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @JohnZwinck solved my problem. Here is the resulting code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323846

//For each value of N, print out how many digits are in N!.

int digits_in_factorial(int n){
    return floor((n+0.5)*log(n) - n+ 0.5*log(2*M_PI))/log(10) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Numarul n este : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int counter = 0;

    counter = digits_in_factorial(n);

    printf("n! are %d cifre", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to answer your own question? Usually people put this sort of thing as an edit to their original question and mark one of the answers provided as being most helpful.

Comment: @Richard Posting it as an answer is the correct way of doing it. He/she can choose to upvote other answers that are helpful and accept one answer (her own or someone elses).

Comment: @KlasLindbäck: Acknowledged. In this case their wording "That's it. Thanks." seems to imply they thought that they were replying to another person's answer.

Comment: @Richard That reference might not be obvious to future readers, so I clarified it. I hope that is ok, Ana-Maria.

Answer (score 0):

OP's recursive method estimates too low:

```
return 1 + how_many(n-1);
```

Should be more like

```
return log10(n) + how_many(n-1);
```

Using OP's original integer approach and below `how_many(32000) --> n! has 123560 digits` - a better estimate.

```
int how_many(int n) {
  if (n <= 3)
    return 1;
  if (n == 4)
    return 2;
  if (n == 5 || n == 6)
    return 3;

  int count = 0 + how_many(n - 1);
  while (n > 3) {
    n /= 10;
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

IAC, OP [has found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888090/2410359) Stirling's method.